# Laravel - Compare comma separated value in database with form data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing an application in which I have a column in MySQL named "tags" and this column has data which was separated by comma just like 1,2,3

I have a form from which I will pass data say 2 and this data should be compared with the data in tags column say 1,2,3

I had written a query like this

```
$linkdetails->where('tags','LIKE',Input::get('tags'))->get();
```

I know that I need to use explode over here but I am quite confused with this Laravel syntax.

Comment: If you're just developing this, rather than being chained by old legacy decisions, then you have no excuse for not normalising your database sensibly

Comment: using `LIKE` is not going to get you the correct results you want to use `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: yeah i know that but this is a demo and if this goes well then i could proceed with normalization and other things..

Comment: Doing this "demo" is going to take more effort than normalising properly would take

Comment: @MarkBaker is totally right. Rather do it right from the beginning. It's a lot easier than changing everything afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your comments MarkBaker and lukasgeiter you were right  but as a programmer what would you ppl do for this scenario @cmorrissey mentioned a solution and its was correct one,can you ppl post something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked nicely here's how I would do it:

1. Create a table `tags` that holds at least a `name` and an `id` and a pivot table `link_tag` with `tag_id` and `link_id`
2. Add a model `Tag`
3. Create the relations. I assume you have something like a `Link` model:

`Link` has a many-to-many relationship with `Tag`

#### Link

```
class Link extends Eloquent {
    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

#### Tag

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    public function links(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Link');
    }
}
```

4. Query link with tag

(`$tags` is a list of tags the link should match)

```
$tags = array('foo', 'bar');
$linkdetails->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags){
    $q->whereIn('name', $tags);
})->get();
```

If you have different entities that can be tagged you should also look into [polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)